# Override parent imports in child?

Tags: python, inheritance

I've been googling to no avail, maybe I'm just not searching for the right thing... What I have is many subclasses from a base. This base would have a method that gets an instance of a class from an imported module. What I want is for the method in the base class to grab the instance of from the module imported in the subclass.

I have a structure like this:

```
root
|--Base
|----foo.py
|----bar.py
|--Child1
|----foo.py
|----bar.py
|--Child2
|----foo.py
|----bar.py
```

Where basically there are a few children that all inherit from Base. What I'm wondering is if it's possible to have a method inherited from Base that uses the subclass's import as such for base classes:

```
# file Base/foo
from root.Base import bar

class Foo(object):
   def get_bar_instance(self):
       return bar.Bar(param)
```

And:

```
# file Base/bar

class Bar(object):
   def do_some_stuff(self):
       print("Base")
```

And then in subclasses:

```
# file Child1/foo
from root.Base import foo
from root.Child1 import bar

class Foo(foo.Foo):
""" Some stuff for subclass only"""
```

And:

```
# file Child1/bar
from root.Base import bar

class Bar(bar.Bar):
   def do_some_stuff(self):
       print("Child1")
```

If I were to do:

```
from root.Child1 import foo

temp_foo = foo.Foo()
temp_bar = temp_foo.get_bar_instance()
temp_bar.do_some_stuff()
```

I would want "Child1" to be printed. Is this possible? Or is there no way to "override" a parent's imports in a submodule. It's kind of hard to explain because it isn't just a print method... I was hoping to have the method in the parent class rather than have the method in every single child

Comment: There are ways to achieve that, but not using normal imports.  Imports pertain to the module (i.e., the file and everything in it), not the class.  You could, though, just give the base class an attribute like `my_bar = root.Base.bar` and have subclasses override that.  In any case, your structure seems a bit strange.  Why are you using that file structure with separate directories for each class?

Comment: Ah yes I didn't think of making an attribute to override, that does indeed work, thanks! As far as my structure... We have different products that each have a different "manager". So in this case, Base would be the base "manager" that has common methods and such for all "managers", and each directory has overrides for only that product. This is for selenium testing scripts if that helps at all. Still new to OOP so maybe I'm going about it wrong